# How to change these global variables to non global variables?

Tags: python, flask

I have this little program that parrots back whatever a user is saying. Right now I'm using two global variables to store the previous variable state and add 1 to it. I'm wondering if someone can please suggest some ways to do this that doesn't involve using global variables.

Note: There is no UI or front end on this thing. Its a webhook for a google home, so its just sitting server side sending things back and forth.

```
import random, time, os, atexit
from datetime import datetime
from random import choice
from random import shuffle
from flask import Flask, current_app, jsonify
from flask_assistant import Assistant, ask, tell, event, context_manager, request
from flask_assistant import ApiAi

app = Flask(__name__)
assist = Assistant(app)
api = ApiAi(os.environ['DEV_ACCESS_TOKEN'], os.environ['CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN'])

random.seed()           
interrupt_count = 0
frustration_level = 0

def reset_things():
    global interrupt_count
    interrupt_count = 0
    print("!reset_things: {0}, {1}".format(interrupt_count, frustration_level))

@assist.action('greeting')
def hello_world():
    speech = 'This is the unxepected machine'
    return ask(speech)

@assist.action('fallback', is_fallback=True)
def say_fallback():
    print(dir(Assistant.request))
    resp = request['result']['resolvedQuery']
    default_resp = "boogie boo"

    # if the user said soemthing
    if resp:
        # update the global variable 
        global interrupt_count
        interrupt_count+=1
        global frustration_level
        if not interrupt_count % 3:
            frustration_level+=1
        print("!fallback: {0}, {1}".format(interrupt_count, frustration_level))
        print(parrot)
        return ask(parrot)
    else:
        print(default_resp)
        return(default_resp)

@assist.action('help')
def help():
    speech = "I am the help section"
    return ask(speech)

@assist.action('quit')
def quit():
    reset_things()
    speech = "Leaving program"
    return tell(speech)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Comment: Use an external storage. Such as a database. That's mandatory for any real server anyway, as you will start several instances and they won't share their variables.

Comment: You could always pass the value of `interrupt_count` back and forth.

Comment: @Antimony can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, for example when you call reset_things(), you can pass the current value of interrupt_count.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would probably be to store the data in a cookie. You don't need a database for the data if it's very small, and it's not important enough to warrant being stored on the server.

Another related possibility is to encode the variable state in the url to your service, and have the service provide the user with an updated url to click on with every reply.

Comment: I should update my post. There's no front end on this thing. Its headless and passing data to a google home. So there's nothing to click on.